# What's a good place to pose an open-ended philosophical question?

Tags: discussion

I know on StackExchange in general they prefer specific questions that can be answered with direct answers, thus I was wondering is there somewhere in the Philosophy StackExchange where I could ask an open-ended philosophical question whose answer is open to individual interpretation? I posted such a question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-you-had-to-make-a-list-of-15-values-that-you-would-like-to-pass-onto-your-children-or-hypothetical-children-as-a-parent-what-would-those-be?), but I was looking to get a response from a multitude of sources to get a better  sample group of information.

Comment: Twitter has polls now...

Comment: It depends, what's the question/link to Quora?

Comment: I've updated my question with the link to Quora if anyone's interested in the content of the question. I'll look into Twitter polls, until I receive further feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I edited my question to better reflect what I was trying to ask. I'm more interested in asking an open-ended question than a poll.